# How to test if a string array is boolean

Tags: c#, arrays, boolean

I need to test for all values being only "0" or "1" in a string array and tried the following code without success:

```
bool isBool = Array.TrueForAll(str, val => val.Trim() == "0" || val.Trim() == "1");
```

and

```
bool isBool = str.All(val => val.Trim() == "0" || val.Trim() == "1");
```

Is there a different way I have to do this because I'm using a || condition?

Comment: Either should work, what's in your array?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question, demonstrating your inputs, your code, the output you're seeing, and the output you want.

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with what you have. Both those work fine.

Comment: Are you saying that either all elements must be "0" or all elements must be "1"?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to test via [`bool.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

you can try Any() and return in the first failing condition `!str.Any(x => x.Trim() != "0" && x.Trim() != "1")`

Comment: `.All()` should do the same shortcutting as `.Any()`. As soon as an element is encountered that matches (or doesn't match for `.All()`) the criteria, it returns. Where is the win?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean the values have to be exclusively all 1's or 0's? In that case you need to test each case separately. Your existing code is true when the array contains only 0's or 1's. It would be false if any of the values were 2 though. One solution:

```
var allAreZero = new string[] { "  0  ", "  0", "  0" };
var allAreOne = new string[] { "  1  ", "1", "  1" };
var mixedOnesAndZeros = new string[] { "  1  ", "0", "  1" };

private bool ArrayIsExclusivelyTrueOrFalse(string[] data)
{
    return data.All(i => int.TryParse(i, out int value) && value == 0) ||
           data.All(i => int.TryParse(i, out int value) && value == 1);
}

ArrayIsExclusivelyTrueOrFalse(allAreZero);          // true
ArrayIsExclusivelyTrueOrFalse(allAreOne);           // true
ArrayIsExclusivelyTrueOrFalse(mixedOnesAndZeros);   // false
```

Comment: @Rufus L - In your answer would it be better to use int.TryParse? The newer implementations use Span as far as I know.

Comment: The string `==` operator will be faster than parsing to an `int` first and then doing the comparison using the int `==` operator.

Comment: @rufus-l I was imagining that the Trim() function would be more expensive that I guess it is. By the way, I don't think `DistinctBy` is part of the standard Linq functions.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that! I didn't realize that was coming from a different assembly I had referenced. I have not measured the difference, but looking at the source code, the [`Trim`](https://aka.ms/AA4e6x8) method just walks the string front to back and back to front until it hits a character that shouldn't be trimmed, then returns that substring (see the  [TrimHelper](https://aka.ms/AA4e6x7)), while the [int.TryParse](https://aka.ms/AA4e6x6) method ends up calling [ParseNumber](https://aka.ms/AA4e6x5), amongst other things, which does all kinds of extra checks and allocations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that all the values in your array are either ALL `"0"` or ALL `"1"` (but not a mix of `"0"` and `"1"`, as I originally read it), then one way would be to ensure that the number of `Distinct` items (after trimming) has a `Count` of `1` (meaning they're all the same), and that the item is a member of the set of valid values (in the code below we just check the first item, since we already know they're all the same at that point).

For example:

```
var validValues = new[] {"0", "1"};
var isBool = str.Select(i => i.Trim()).Distinct().Count() == 1 &&
             validValues.Contains(str[0].Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var isBool = !str.Select(s => s.Trim()).Distinct().Any(s => s != "0" && s != "1");
```

Comment: Why should he try this? And, more important, how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: Uwe here is OP's question that's been addressed  "Is there a different way I have to do this because I'm using a || condition?"
- Is there a different way  YES.
- with not using a || condition.